# get color of element in D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

For the following `d3` codes:

```
var previousElement = d3.select(this);
console.log(previousElement.attr("style"));
```

The result is like:

```
fill: red;
```

or

```
fill: rgb(152, 223, 138);
```

Then how can I get the exact color of this element, so that I may doing a judge like:

```
if ( elementColor == 'red')
```

or

```
if (elementColor == 'rgb(152, 223, 138)')
```

I tried `var elementColor = previousElement.attr("style").fill`, it returns `null`.

Comment: Have you looked at the color documentation for d3, https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Colors?

Comment: If you are confident for the word as fill, then just check as elementColor = "fill: red"

Comment: Just curious, any reason to down vote?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe what you want is `previousElement.style('fill')` instead of using `.attr('style')`. See https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#style for documentation.

You may also want to look at the D3 Colors documentation, https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Colors, as that may help you even more.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`d3.rgb()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Colors#d3_rgb) to parse whatever is specified as the style and then compare the R, G, and B components:

```
var colour = d3.rgb(previousElement.attr("style"));
if(colour.r == 255 && colour.g == 0 && colour.b == 0) {
  // ...
}
```